# List in Python and sorting based on index with duplicate element

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to sort the list2 by using list1
    l

```
    ist1 = [7, 9, 12, 1, 4, 7]
    list2 = ['p','e','b','a','y','i']
```

the output should be

```
['a','y','p','i','e','b']
```

the p has the pair with 7 of smaller index

Answer (score 2):

```
[item[1] for item in sorted(zip(list1,list2))]
```